# Localization from .json file [swift]

Tags: json, swift, localization

I need to do localization for different language from a api, which get a json response, and i have already done with the parsing part and save the response as .json file and add as a library inside my project, but how do i match the key with all the strings? Can someone guide me and maybe provide me some tutorial or example for me to follow?

Comment: What do you mean by matching the key with all the strings? You have a json file where values are in English and you want to create the same file with values in another language? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I make an example.
I don't know if I help you.
[How to make Localizable in SWIFT APP](http://shellykaohsiung.blogspot.tw/2016/07/swift-how-to-make-localizable-in-swift.html)

1.Open Xcode and click  File->New->Project

2.Create a new project and choose Single View Application.

3.Input "Localizable" as app name

4. On "Localizable" app name , right click  and choose New File.
5. click "Resource" , "Strings File"
6. input "Localizable.strings" as file name

7.click "Localize"

8. please choose "Base" and click "Localize"

9.To find "info" of "Localizations", and click add "+"

10. choose your language to your app
11. choose "Localizable.strings", and click "Finish"
12. You will have two files called "Localizable.strings"